# Unable to provision resources in sequence on AWS

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to provision VPC, CIDR Block, Internet Gateway, NAT Gateway, Subnets, NACLs, Security Groups, Windows EC2 instances, AWS Managed AD, KMS CMK for encrypting EBS volumes attached to EC2 instances, but facing errors stating that VPC has reached the maximum limit, and Internet gateway has reached the maximum limit.

When analyzed the code, it was found that VPC and Internet gateway gets created multiple times from each module. Please advise how to provision the above resources in sequence.

Comment: Please post the code you have to the question. AWS has some limits for the number of certain types of resources you can provision, so you might be hitting that due to misconfiguration in your terraform code. Also, please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.